# SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2008: possible to restore a 2000 database to a 2008 schema?

Tags: sql-server-2008, schema, sql-server-2000, database-restore

Let's say we have two SQL Server 2000  databases:

```
           PARTS
           CUSTOMERS
```

Can they be restored to SQL Server 2008 into one combined database but separated using schemas, so there would be a PARTS schema and a CUSTOMERS schema? Can a 2000 database be restored "into a 2008 schema"?

Answer (score 2):

> Q: Is it possible to restore a 2000 database to a 2008 schema?

A: Yes.  If you have a .bak backup file, you should be able to simply "restore".

Here's a link of somebody who had problems doing a similar restore, and how they were resolved:

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/ce5e84f9-95a2-4c8a-80ab-abaf3e261afc

You can absolutely do a "restore with replace".

Once you've restored the old MSSQL 2000 backup (e.g. into a temp database), you can do a "select into" or whatever you want to copy and/or merge the data into a different database (perhaps with a different schema).

As far as "backup" files are concerned, there are relatively few issues with using an MSSQL 2000 backup in an MSSQL 2008 environment - compatibility is pretty good.

IMHO .. PSM

Comment: No, I don't think this is correct. He wants to restore a database called PARTS where the tables and other objects are restored into another database's schema.

Comment: This is not what he's asking. He's asking if two separate databases can be restored to one combined database.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot restore two databases into a single database. You'll need to restore each database individually and then combine them manually. Or, you can create a T-SQL script of each database, combine the two scripts appropriately and then execute the script.

Comment: But you *can* get the old data from an MSSQL 2000 backup.  Once you've got the data into your MSSQL 2008 environment, there are lots of techniques for merging the data.  The backup itself is *not* a problem.  "Merging" *is* a problem - regardless of where the data came from.

Comment: I have been programming in SQL Server 2000 but worked for a few years with Oracle (ORA is my only experience with Schemas).  In Oracle, the schema owns the securable (aka database object), so it would be possible, to follow my example above, to have PARTSSCHEMA.FOO and CUSTOMERSSCHEMA.FOO objects in the same database. So I was hoping it was simply possible to restore the SQL 2K database in such a way that the target schema claimed ownership of the securables during the restore, saving me the trouble of having to "merge" the objects manually.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can achieve what you're after without manipulating the restored database on the 2008 instance leveraging schemas.

When you back up the source database (in your case two), it is contained it will be restored as is on the destination, that's the main point, avoid any discrepancies between copies. Therefore, by definition, it shouldn't allow you to have a restore result which is structurally different the backed up database.

A way to achieve this would be to handle the backup/restore process first and then write a script that takes the restored databases and combine them to the actual structure you wish to have.

I hope this was helpful.

Comment: Correct: "I don't think you can achieve what you're after without manipulating the restored database on the 2008 instance leveraging schemas.".  *Restoring* the database isn't a problem.  *Combining* (the way the OP wants) will take a little work.  And the issue has *nothing* to do with MSSQL 2000 vs MSSQL 2008.  IMHO...

Comment: agreed, though the more I think of it, maybe that combining script while being straightforward, won't be able to avoid copying the objects (expensive) from the restored to the separated schema. I can see how it makes sense logically to do it, but maybe the best approach here is to use DBNAME..TABLENAME for queries and replace other schema advantages by other means.

Comment: What I would like to do is a restore legacy databases into an arbitrary (specified) 2008 database, in such a way that the objects being restored are "claimed" by a designated schema. In that way, the objects would be logically distinct but physically in the same database, so that declarative referential integrity constraints could be used; in the legacy database RI had to be enforced with SPs because the objects were in different databases.